# How to use a different "template" on Ionic/Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-router

I've one ionic app with the menu on the left.

The app.component.html has the `ion-router-outlet` and all the menu:

```
<ion-app>
  <ion-split-pane contentId="main-content">
    <ion-menu contentId="main-content" type="overlay">
      <ion-content>
        <!-- Profile part -->
        <div class="ion-text-center">
          <div *ngIf="isLoggedIn$ | async" class="ion-text-center">
              <img
                ngxGravatar
                [email]="email$ | async"
                fallback="mp"
                size="80"
              />
            <ion-button (click)="doLogout()" color="danger">
              Logout
            </ion-button>
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="(isLoggedIn$ | async) === false">
            <ion-button (click)="doLogin()" color="success">Login</ion-button>

          </div>

        </div>
        <ion-list id="labels-list">
          <ion-list-header>Labels</ion-list-header>

          <ion-item *ngFor="let label of labels" lines="none">
            <ion-icon
              slot="start"
              ios="bookmark-outline"
              md="bookmark-sharp"
            ></ion-icon>
            <ion-label>{{ label }}</ion-label>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-menu>
    <ion-router-outlet id="main-content"></ion-router-outlet>
  </ion-split-pane>
</ion-app>
```

I would like to know if it's possible to use a totally different template for some routes ? By example, if I've a sign in/sign up page, I don't want to have any menu.

The menu is one example, but I could imagine a lot of different scenarios, with totally different layouts.

How to do this? I could put some *ngIf in the base template, but I will make a lot of them.

Comment: any specific reason for using ion-router-outlet?

Comment: it's an ionic app and the default generated app, why?

Answer (score 0):

You have a event on ion-router-outlet i.e. activate which will let you know which component is loaded in router outlet. You can use it like :-

**HTML**

```
<ion-router-outlet id="main-content" (activate) = "changeTemplate($event)"></ion-router-outlet>
```

**TS:-**

```
hideMenu=false;
changeTemplate(component: any) {
   if(component instanceof SigninPage) {
     this.hideMenu = true;
   }
}
```

Use flags like hideMenu in your template with ngIf.

Comment: Yes I see, but this has the same drawback than just asking my service if I'm logged in or not.

Comment: Can you please explain the drawback you are talking about?

Comment: A lot of ngIf to put, and maybe a lot of flags to manage

Comment: wasn't that your original thought to have conditional templates? and number of flags depends on number of conditional templates you have.

Comment: yes but I would like to have a whole different template if I use another (login) page. For some things it's just hiding some options in a menu, for some other things, it's having the same information at different place. With your proposal, it's like having 2 totally different pages mixed in one, and trying to have the structure of each page not falling appart

Comment: then go for nested router outlets and have different layouts in parent routes https://medium.com/dev-genius/the-art-of-nested-router-outlets-in-angular-dafb38245a30